# C# clear contents of NumericUpDown on form open

Tags: c#, winforms, numericupdown

I have been searching to no avail if there is a way to clear the contents of a numericUpDown when a form is first opened and make it blank. It currently opens with a "0" in it and I do not want that. I just want it to be blank.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "cleared completely". You can set it to 0 with `NumericUpDown.Value = 0` and put that in the `Form Load` event.

Comment: @Equalsk I made my question a bit more clear. I essentially want the form blank when it first opens. The user of my program has to delete what is in it to type the number they want.

Comment: You can make it look empty with `NumericUpDown.Text = ""` but it will still have the value 0 'behind the scenes'. You'd need to make sure to do some validation.

Comment: @Equalsk That is weird. I tried that and it did not work. Tried it again and not it DOES work.

Comment: It happens to the best of us. Glad it worked ;-)